# Polymer return drop-down selected value back to parent element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Below are the two polymer elements 
1. cc-dropdown 
2. product-page 
product-page is parent element here, which is not getting the changed value {{selectedData}} back from child, it just empty value from beginning.

am i missing something here?

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="cc-dropdown">
  <template>
    {{selectedData}}
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Environment">
      <paper-menu id="ccdropdown" class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{selectedData}}">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
          <paper-item value="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'cc-dropdown',
        properties: {
          selectedData: {
            notify: true,
            reflectToAttribute: true
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>

---------------

<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="cc-product-page">
  <template>
    {{selectedData}}
    <cc-dropdown data="{{Env}}" selected="{{selectedData}}"></cc-dropdown>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'cc-product-page',

        properties: {
          Env: {
            type: Array,
            value: ["STAGE", "QA", "PROD"],
            notify: true
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be my bad, below is the way to use cc-dropdown in parent component product-page, which reflects the changes back to parent.

1. Attribute value should be selected-data (not selected)
2. Attribute has to have "-" as above 
   selectedData should be passed as selected-data

```html
<cc-dropdown id="envOptions" data="{{Env}}" selected-data="{{selectedData}}"></cc-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{selectedData}}` needs to be in it's own html element. Try `<span>{{selectedData}}</span>` instead.

Comment: Tried it, but no luck, actually it reflects the change in the component itself with just {{selectedData}}

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael.Lumley said you should have `{{selectedData}}` in it's own HTML-element as he demonstrated.

I think a more clean solution would be to change this:

```
 <template>
    {{selectedData}}
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Environment">
      <paper-menu id="ccdropdown" class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{selectedData}}">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
          <paper-item value="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </template>
```

To this:

```
 <template>
    <span>{{selectedData}}</span>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Environment" value="{{selectedData}}">
      <paper-menu id="ccdropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
          <paper-item>{{item}}</paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </template>
```

The paper-dropdown-menu has a property, `value`, that will change whenever you change the dropdown.

According to documentation regarding the value property:

> The value for this element that will be used when
>   submitting in a form. It is read only, and will always have the same
>   value as selectedItemLabel.

`selectedItem` property will return the whole `paper-item` element and that is probably not what you want.

Note: I'm not sure where you get the `{{item}}` from (typo?).

Comment: okay that make sense, so that no need to specify attr-for-selected, {{item}} is not a typo, it is the for each loop instance, we do not need to specify the name explicitly, it is {{item}} by default to save some keystrokes.